# Почему Pylint выдает ошибку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylint

Вот код на Python

```
a = [0] * 5
for i in range(5):
    a[i] = [0] * 5

a[2][3] = 7

t = 2
a[t][3] = 7

for i in range(5):
    a[i][3] = 7

s = "qwerty"
s[2] = "x"
```

Pylint выдает следующие проблемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, когда я запускаю программу, ошибка выдается только на строке `s[2] = "x"`, что ожидаемо, т.к. строки в Python неизменяемые.

А вот значение переменной в двумерном списке отлично изменяется.

Еще я специально добавил цикл, т.к. внутри него никакая ошибка не выдается.

Отсюда вопрос: почему Pylint выдает эту ошибку?

И если эта ошибка... ошибочна, то как сделать так, чтобы она не выдавалась?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мое предположение такое: pylint видит что переменная инициализирована как список целых чисел (нулей), потом какой-то код, а потом идет попытка обращения к одному из элементов списка (числу с точки зрения pylint) через индекс (типа `0[3] = 7`). Правда, почему-то он не ругается на присваивание внутри второго цикла for.

Варианты решения:

1. Инициализировать переменную списком из пустых списков (на самом деле в каждом элементе будет лежать один и тот же список, но потом они в любом случае будут перезаписаны):

   ```
   a = [[]] * 5
   for i in range(5):
       a[i] = [0] * 5

   a[2][3] = 7
   ```

   Метод так себе, просто костыль, чтобы "удовлетворить" pylint.
2. Отключаем диагностику для нужных строк. Для этого запускаем `pylint имя_файла.py` из командной строки, смотрим код (или название) предупреждения, добавляем комментарии к проблемным строкам, чтобы pylint игнорировал их:

   ```
   a = [0] * 5
   for i in range(5):
       a[i] = [0] * 5

   # Через название ошибки
   a[2][3] = 7  # pylint: disable=unsupported-assignment-operation

   t = 2
   # или через код
   a[t][3] = 7  # pylint: disable=E1137
   ```
3. Однострочником инициализируем переменную как двумерный массив:

   ```
   a = [[0 for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)]
   ```